# Calling a list as an array from a .txt and need to display an average

Tags: java, arrays

The .txt file looks like this:

```
Gator Ali 85
Vator Ella 75
Beam James 95
Lastin Class 55
```

I've seen other people trying to get similar code on here, but none of that helped.
I can get the average; however, I also need to print out if the score 10 points below average.
Here is my output: 
run:

Welcome to the Student Scores Application.

```
Ali Gator 85
Ella Vator 75
James Beam 95
Class Lastin 55
Beam, James: 95
Gator, Ali: 85
Lastin, Class: 55
Vator, Ella: 75

Your score is 10 points or more below the class average

Class Average: 77.5
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("src//chapt11//Studentdata.txt"));
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Scores Application.\n");

    int nStudent = 100;
    Student[] studentArray = new Student[nStudent];
    int counter = 0;
    while (aScanner.hasNext()) {
        String lastName = aScanner.next();
        String firstName = aScanner.next();
        int score = aScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + score);
        studentArray[counter++] = new Student(lastName, firstName, score);  
        Arrays.sort(studentArray, 0, counter); 
    } 

    System.out.println();

    for(int j = 0; j < counter; j++){  
        System.out.println(studentArray[j]);
    }

    double sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < counter; j++){    
        sum += studentArray[j].getExamScore();
    }
    double average = (sum*1.0)/counter;

    for(int j = 0; j < counter; j++){    
        int score = studentArray[j].getExamScore();
        if (score <= (average - 10)){
             System.out.println("Your score is 10 points or more below the class average");
        } 
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Class Average: " + average);

    System.out.println();
    aScanner.close();  
}

class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int score;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int score) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.score = score;
}

public int getExamScore() {
    return score;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Student s) {
    if(!firstName.equalsIgnoreCase( s.firstName)) {
        return firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(s.firstName);
    }
    if(!lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(s.lastName)) {
        return lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(s.lastName);
    }
        return score - s.score;
    }
 @Override 
 public String toString(){ 
        return firstName + ", " + lastName + ": "+ score;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening? What do you want to happen? Which line of code do you suspect is the problem?

Comment: I've edited it to show my output..."Your score is 10 points or more below the class average" should be next to Lastin, Class: 55 because 55 falls 10 points below average but I don't know how to get it there.  There relevant code is in the if statement : if(score <= (average - 10)

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems with your code.

Firstly, there is no need to call `Arrays.sort` every time you add a `Student` to the `studentArray`. Place this method call outside the end of `while` which sorts complete array with just one call to the method.

Secondly, and more importantly, how do you want the `Student` objects compared?

The `compareTo` method inside `Student` doesn't make sense. If you want the students to be sorted only by their scores you should have something like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student s) {
    return this.score - s.score;
}
```

And as far as the expected output is concerned, this is what's happening.

The following line prints each `Student` as they are added to the array:

```
System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + score);
```

This part prints each `Student` object again:

```
for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
    System.out.println(studentArray[j]);
}
```

And this line gets printed *only* when `score <= (average - 10)` evaluates to true:

```
System.out.println("Your score is 10 points or more below the class average");
```

I believe now you see the problem.